# Spring boot. How to Create TaskExecutor with Annotation?

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, concurrency

I did a `@Service` class in Spring Boot application with one of the methods that should run asynchronously. As I read method should be `@Async` annotated and also I have to run a `TaskExecutor` bean. But in Spring manual http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html I not find any info or example how to run `TaskExecutor` with annotation, without XML config. Is it possible to create `TaskExecutor` bean in Spring Boot without XML, with annotations only? Here my Service class:

```
@Service
public class CatalogPageServiceImpl implements CatalogPageService {

    @Override
    public void processPagesList(List<CatalogPage> catalogPageList) {
        for (CatalogPage catalogPage:catalogPageList){
            processPage(catalogPage);
        }
    }

    @Override
    @Async("locationPageExecutor")
    public void processPage(CatalogPage catalogPage) {
        System.out.println("print from Async method "+catalogPage.getUrl());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Add a `@Bean` method to your Spring Boot application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class MySpringBootApp {

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(5);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(25);
        return executor;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

See [Java-based container configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java) in the Spring Framework reference documentation on how to configure Spring using Java config instead of XML.

(Note: You don't need to add `@Configuration` to the class because `@SpringBootApplication` already includes `@Configuration`).

Comment: I create as you mention and it makes a bean (I can "@Autowire" it in my test class just to know it exist), but my service method not run asynchronously. Here my method description: "@Bean public TaskExecutor locationPageExecutor()". Could you comment?

Comment: Any way looks like you answered my initial question, so I'll look how to solve new issue. Thanks.

Comment: @Pavlo You also have to add `@EnableAsync` to your Spring boot app class, see: [Enable scheduling annotations](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-enable-annotation-support)

Comment: the java-based container configuration url is deprecated. see https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch03s11.html

Comment: @teek thanks for noticing, I'll update my answer; but the URL you posted in your comment is for an old version of the Spring Framework. The URL for the current docs is here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java

Comment: If I set queue capacity to 50 which is full and suppose my core pool size threads are not complete, what happens to my 51st task? will it get rejected or will the Async method caller wait?

Comment: @KCK It depends on what implementation of `TaskExecutor` you use. Spring's [`ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html) creates new threads until max pool size is reached. If there are more than the max then tasks are put in a queue which by default has unlimited capacity. Those tasks will run when a thread becomes available.

Answer (score 15):

UPDATE: as of **Spring Boot 2.1**, there is no need to create the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` through code, since **`ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` is the default** and can be completely **configured using properties** prefixed with `spring.task.execution`.

So, steps:

1. use `@EnableAsync` in a `@Configuration`-annotated class,
2. annotate one or more methods with `@Async`
3. optionally override the default `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` config with properties

Properties example:

```
spring.task.execution.pool.core-size=1
spring.task.execution.pool.max-size=20
spring.task.execution.pool.keep-alive=120s
spring.task.execution.pool.queue-capacity=1000
spring.task.execution.shutdown.await-termination=true
spring.task.execution.shutdown.await-termination-period=5m
spring.task.execution.thread-name-prefix=async-executor-
spring.task.execution.pool.allow-core-thread-timeout=false
```

If more customization is required, one can also implement the `TaskExecutorCustomizer` interface, for example (in kotlin):

```kotlin
@Component
class AsyncExecutorCustomizer : TaskExecutorCustomizer {
    override fun customize(taskExecutor: ThreadPoolTaskExecutor?) {
        taskExecutor?.let { executor ->
            executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is since Spring Boot 2.1 see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1-Release-Notes#task-execution

Answer (score 13):

First – let’s go over the rules – @Async has two limitations:

- it must be applied to public methods only
- self-invocation – calling the async method from within the same class – won’t work

So your processPage() method should be in separate class

Comment: @Async don't need to be public (at least no longer need to)

Comment: upvoted for the self-invocation remark, looking back it should have been obvious but wasn't for me either :)