# ExecutorService should be alive for whole life of bean or should have narrow(method) scope

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, executorservice

I have a method, which has to process thousand of documents.

It takes time in normal processing so I use `ExecutorService` to reduce processing time by having multiple threads working in parallel.

I have to use this method for processing of two long lists.

1. Approach 1 of handling `ExecutorService`:

Right now , I have initialized `ExecutorService` within method and shutting down it in same method. (which is called twice)

So it leads to creation and shutting down of `ExecutorService` twice.

```
  private List<DocDTO> convertData(args) {
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);

    List<Future<Set<DocDTO>>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<Set<DocDTO>>>();

    for (Pro pro : pros.getPros()) {
        Callable<Set<DocDTO>> callable = new Callable<Set<DocDTO>>() {
            public Set<DocDTO> call() throws Exception {        
                for loop code
            }
        };
        futures.add(service.submit(callable));
    }

    service.shutdown();
    for (Future<Set<DocDTO>> future : futures) {
        if (future.get() != null) {
            list.addAll(future.get());
        }
    }   
}
```

2. Approach 2 of handling `ExecutorService`:

I was looking at below link:

http://programtalk.com/java/executorservice-not-shutting-down/

Author has created `ExecutorService` at Class level.

Could you please tell me if it is good idea to have `ExecutorService` created at method level or class level?

FYI , method in above code gets executed twice in a day

Answer (score 2):

The *natural* choice is to make such a service a **class** field.

Establishing such a service doesn't come for free. You spent that overhead for "building" that thread pool; and the time to properly shut it down - each time that method is called.

Most of the time, that is not what you want. You want to spend that time once (like: when the object holding the service gets created).

The one downside: now the "life time" of the class holding the service matters. As you now *might* have to worry about explicit calls to `shutdown()` the service owned by that holder class.

In other words: when you have to worry about performance, then you would probably change the service to be a field of a class.

But: you explicitly state that this method is called two times per day. Then you absolutely do not need to worry about the *overhead* generated by creating/closing down that service. Even when the overhead would result in 1 second of computing time - 2 seconds per day do simply not matter at all.

So, given *that* requirement - my (personal) advise: keep your code as is. Don't touch a running system until there is a *real* problem to fix.

Comment: Thanks GhostCat for comment, right now my code  is in not in prod. So I am thinking of all options .  Do you suggest anything on "How can i mention that method is called two times per day"

Comment: That is kinda "hard". I would add that to the javadoc of that method; and maybe put a `// service is local to method for simplicity; assuming that method is called just a few times per day` above the service instantiation.

Comment: ok, one thing here that having pool for lifetime of bean will have more resources usage(memory and time ) or creating ExecutorService pool each time I call that method(for my case, twice per day)  , just a guess would be ok for this and does preDestroy method will not guarantee the execution of  "shutdown()" for shutting down of Thread Pool before bean destrutcion .

Comment: Thanks Maleen and GhostCat for your valuable comments, i dropped plan of using multiple threads as I was getting different results from the method  while running from single thread and multiple thread. One more reason, ExecutorService does not work with Lazy relationship. Instead I optimized the way how I was loading entities rather than using multi threading .

Comment: Sounds interesting. If you can turn that comment into a self answer (with some more content) I guess I would upvote it. Drop me comment then.

Answer (score 1):

First I would recommend you to read this [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) where you can understand how to use spring to enable a task executor service. As correctly suggested by GhostCat it should be in class level. Further I would suggest is creating a seperate bean for it.

Ex:

```
@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(5);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(25);
    return executor;
}
```

I got it from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38370063/spring-boot-how-to-create-taskexecutor-with-annotation) answer, but there are plenty of different configuration you can find on internet.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Maleen and GhostCat for your valuable comments, i dropped plan of using multiple threads because of two reasons:

- I was getting different results from the same method while running from single thread and multiple thread
- ExecutorService does not work with Lazy relationship. So changing Entities' loading from Lazy to Eager might affect other functionality performance

Instead I optimized the way how I was loading entities rather than using multi threading. Previously, I was loading all static data from database one by one in for loop and saving it in EhCache .

After change I loaded all static data in one go using findall methods and saved in map and accessed same data from map in for loop . It increased performance of method a lot. Thank you again to both of you.