# Use executors for bulk update using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, bulkinsert, executors

Use executors for bulk update. Try to persist 10-20 records in a database using executors. using spring boot jpa hibernate.Pleask help me how to proceed

Comment: this can help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38370063/spring-boot-how-to-create-taskexecutor-with-annotation

Comment: Hello, but how to insert data

Comment: How to use post method here for insertion.Please help.

Comment: Hello,Thanks a lot this helped me a lot and it is working now.

Comment: Welcome! Cheers